# What exactly is the HttpInterceptor in Angular?

Tags: angular, keycloak, angular-http-interceptors, pkce, angular-oauth2-oidc

What exactly is the HttpInterceptor in Angular?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localhost:4200 should be what you add to "allowedUrls". This tells the auth server that requests from your angular app are "allowed".

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding. You would check for the bearer token.